# Send selected cells from a row via email

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am starting with Google Scripts and I was hoping to create a sheet that could email selected cells from a row. What I want to do by selecting Send Email at the end of a row it then selects pre defined cells on the said row and then emails it. I created something in VBA for Excel that does the same trick as shown below.

I am essentially trying to replicate what I have done below using Google Sheets if possible to do via Scripts. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r As Long
If Target.Count = 1 Then

    If Target.Value = "Send Email" Then
        r = Target.Row
        With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
            .Subject = Cells(r, 5).Text
            .Body = "============" & vbNewLine & Cells(r, 7).Text & vbNewLine & "============" & vbNewLine & Cells(r, 6).Text
            .To = Cells(r, 4).Text
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "7828691"
            .Display
        End With

End If 
End Sub
```

I have also attached my Google sheet so far to show an example.

[Here is my Google Sheet so far](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hEX_YlTVgTyXbHlXbZgy4mVaYvYrNKD385snp4aTH3w/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's possible to insert a button (Insert > Drawing) and assign a script to it, the resulting buttons float over the sheet in their own layer, not being bound to any cell. This wouldn't work for you since you want the action to be related to a particular row of the sheet.

Instead, I would use a custom item of the main menu, added by the function `onOpen` below, every time the spreadsheet is open (so, after entering the script you'll need to close and open the spreadsheet for it to appear). The menu command "send email" sends email using the data from the active row (the one where the cursor is now). It doesn't matter where in the row the cursor is.

Otherwise the logic is pretty straightforward: get the handle of the active sheet, get the number of the active row, get values in the active row, use them to compose an email.

```
function sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var values = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 10).getValues();   // or how many columns you want from that row; 10 seem to be enough for your data
  var recipient = values[0][2];   // indices of JavaScript are 0-based.  
  var subject = values[0][3];     // 0th row of the acquired range, 3rd column
  var body = values[0][6] + '\n========\n' + values[0][4]; 
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}  

function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: "Send Email", functionName: "sendEmail"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom", menu);
}
```

You can add options with

```
var options = {cc: 'someemail@gmail.com', replyTo: 'another@gmail.com'};
```

or

```
var options = {cc: values[0][7], replyTo: values[0][8]};
```

if you take them from the spreadsheet. Then the sending command will be

```
MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options);
```

Comment: Wow this is awesome Normal Human. Is it also possible to Carbon Copy (cc) and sent on behalf of? Or is this something that cat be done?

Comment: You can add `cc` and `replyTo` as options: see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)). No "on behalf of" that I know of.

Comment: Hi Normal Human. This is now the amended code but the cc is not working, any ideas? (see below)

Comment: So Normal Human if I want to always CC my email address (which is neosegauk@gmail.com) whenever I send an email using your code above in my spreadsheet what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Did you read what I added to my answer?

Comment: Also sorry I deleted my answer bellow which was the wrong way of asking the question on here (sorry about that I am still new to stack)

Comment: Ah Normal Human, thanks I just read above and that is mega. I will try an Implement this tomorrow in my code and edit my question above to show the full answer. You have been very helpful and again I am sorry If I have been a bit confusing with my approach on all of this. New to stack but I am getting used to it. You rock.

Comment: If we ever meet in real life Normal Human I O U a beer ^_^

Comment: One last thing here Almost Human. I have seen a few folks ask for things like this on Google Sheets. It maybe worth sharing the code via Google Add Ons. Surprised no one has already (there are some but they are not very good).